# How to generate access token for user using oauth 2.0, password credentials as authorization grant type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am setting up a spring boot application of version 3.1.5 using spring security with OAuth 2.0 and trying to generate access token for user ,I can get access token only if the authorization grant type is as "Client Credentials or Authorization Code" where this token represents client access token but not user token.

I want to get access token using grant type as password credentials but password credentials grant type is deprecated what is the alternative way to generate access token for user by using both username and password.

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. This is not a "how to" website, what have you tried? show us your work and we will gladly help correcting a mistake

Comment: As you have pointed out, the implicit flow has been deprecated, because that flow cant guarentee that a token is handed out to the client that asked for it. The recommended flow is using Authorization Code flow with PKCE. And no there is no workaround, and you should not hand out tokens directly to endusers because of the security reasons i mentioned above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.